Windows authentification infinite pop-up for remote users
So I have a dotnet web app deployed with IIS on a Windows server 2019, this web app uses Windows authentication and the problem that I have is that when I try to connect like to the webapp directly from the server itself using the URL ('myapp.eti.domain.net') which I linked to the localhost IP address in the hosts' file ("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts") it works, so I'm asked for my credentials then I get access to the website, however, the users trying to access the website remotely, they see the pop-up asking for their credentials showing up again and again even with putting correct credentials.
I hope that you can help and if you need more details, don't hesitate to ask me.
For more details, the users are getting a 401 HTTP error like they open the network dev tool, and also in the site's URL 'myapp.eti.domain.net' is already in the local intranet zone for the users
I tried a lot of solutions that I found on stack overflow like: setting the value of DisableLoppBackCheck to 1, checking that NTLM is the first provider, checking that only Windows authentification is enabled, checking the identity used by the app pool .......

Hi Zine, could you kindly check what happened when we force Kerberos authentication in IIS ? As we know the NTLM, Negotiate not working in this issue, we can give it a try.

Finally I figure out the issue, please kindly check my answer in this thread.
